# Expected unqualified-id before unsigned in C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, dns

I'm trying to make a struct that resembles a DNS header, but I keep getting compile errors:

`error: expected unqualified-id before ‘unsigned’`

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef RAW_DNS_TYPES_H
#define RAW_DNS_TYPES_H

struct RawDNSHeader
{
    unsigned short int ID;
    unsigned int QR:1;
    unsigned int OPCode:4;
    unsigned int AA:1;
    unsigned int TC:1;
    unsigned int RD:1;
    unsigned int RA:1;
    unsigned int Z:3;
    unsigned int RCode:4;
    unsigned short int QDCount;
    unsigned short int ANCount;
    unsigned short int NSCount;
    unsigned short int ARCount;
};

struct RawDNSPacket
{
    RawDNSHeader header;
    unsigned char body[0];
};

#endif
```

Edit:
I've added the entire source code as requested.

Comment: Which line is that error on?

Comment: The problem is likely to be with the code immediately before this. Add some more context.

Comment: You shouldn't make any assumptions about the sizes of `short` or `int`  That's why you have explicitly-sized types in `<cctype>`.  You also shouldn't make assumptions about padding in your struct, nor the layout and ordering of bitfields (which is implementation-defined).

Comment: @Barmar I have added the entire source file.

Comment: @Barmar The error was occuring on the line with QR.

Comment: @paddy thanks, but do you have any idea what may be causing the error?

Comment: The problem may be in the file that `#include`s this file.

Comment: I created a main program with `#include "raw_dns_types.h"` and I didn't get an error. Show the main program that includes this.

Comment: Have you done `#define ID ...` somewhere else in your code, by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I left my desk for 15 minutes, and when I returned, everything compiled fine. Given the resolution, I can't give many details on the cause of the issue I was having, but I suspect that it had to do with the files `#include`-ing this one as Barmar pointed out.